# Different position of text by flatten pdf with iText

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext

I have a problem with iText and flatten form fields in pdfs.

I submit a pdf with form fields created in Acrobat to my java method. On a website i have created a form to fill the form fields in the pdf. The form fields are filled correctly, but as soon as i flatten the document the text is moved to a little different position. The biggest difference is seen in multiline form fields. There the text is at the border of the field in the upper left. In Acrobat and before flattening the text has a padding to the top.

Here is my java code to call the methods of iText:

```
PdfReader template = new PdfReader(templ);
XfdfReader xfdfReader = new XfdfReader(xfdf);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(template, outputStream, '\0');

AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();                                            

Set<String> fields = form.getFields().keySet();

form.setFields(xfdfReader);

stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(true);            
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);    
stamper.close();
template.close();
```

Anyone has an idea why the text is moving when i flatten the pdf? How can I avoid this?

I allready tried different versions from iText. From version 4.X to 5.X. The difference appears in all versions.

Although i tried to move the form fields in the code of iText, but then the whole field is moving and the difference of the position is much bigger and not predictable.

In my project the text must be at the exact same position as in Acrobat, so i must find a workaround for this misbehavior. I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The position of the baseline of a field in a PDF file has been changed over the years. You'll even see differences depending on the version of Acrobat you are using. There is no solution for your problem unless you know the exact offset. If you do, you can use http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setExtraMargin%28float,%20float%29 to change the offset of all fields when flattening the document.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for the tip!!! This was the clue to find the solution for me. If you post it as an answer i will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the baseline of a field in a PDF file has been changed over the years. You'll even see differences depending on the version of Acrobat you are using.

There is no solution for your problem unless you know the exact offset. If you do, you can use the [`setExtraMargin()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setExtraMargin%28float,%20float%29) method to change the offset of all fields when flattening the document.

We created this method to deal with specific forms that have a baseline that is different from what is to be expected. Which values you choose can be different for different forms.

Comment: does not exist in itext7